# Swift: How to keep updating a Dictionary inside another Dictionary correctly?

Tags: swift, dictionary

This is a little hard to explain, but I'll try my best. I am trying to update a Dictionary inside another Dictionary properly. The following code almost does what I need.

```
var dictionary = Dictionary<String, [Int : Int]>()

func handleStatsValue(tag: Int ) {
        let currentValue: Int = dictionary["Score"]?[tag] ?? 0

        dictionary["Score"] = [
            tag : currentValue + 1
        ]
 }
```

However, it seems the dictionary is overridden when the `tag` value changes (e.g. 1 to 2). I need `Dictionary` to have multiple dictionaries inside of it. Any tips or suggestions are deeply appreciated.

Edit: I'm trying to have multiple dictionaries nested inside a dictionary. It seems whenever the `tag` value is changed, the dictionary is overridden.

Comment: How can `tag` change at all? By definition it is a key and not a value and should be considered immutable.

Comment: Generally, avoid nested dictionaries entirely, and I'd also advise against using tags, for most things.

Comment: Better use structs than dictionaries for this use case. What do you mean by *"if the tag key changes (e.g. 1 to 2), the previous tag key loses its value"*? Could you give a concrete example, with the expected result?

Comment: What code are you using to change/add a `tag`?

Comment: The tag is based on which UIButton was touched. I am trying to create nested dictionaries that keep track of each tag's value. However, the following code seems to only allow 1 nested dictionary. I believe it is because it's being overridden.

Comment: @CurtRand that's because the key `"Score"` can only have one value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to write this would be:

```
func handleStatsValue(tag: Int) {
    dictionary["Score", default: [:]][tag, default: 0] += 1
}
```

or, written without `[_:default:]`

```
func handleStatsValue(tag: Int) {
    var scoreDictionary = dictionary["Score"] ?? [:]
    scoreDictionary[tag] = (scoreDictionary[tag] ?? 0) + 1
    dictionary["Score"] = scoreDictionary
}
```

However, it's not a good idea to use nested dictionaries to keep your data. Use a custom `struct` instead and try to avoid tags too:

```
struct DataModel {
    var score: [Int: Int] = [:]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works. I now see where I went wrong. I will definitely switch to structs because it looks a lot cleaner and easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: Definitely shorter than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this to either increase the value for an existing tag or add a new tag if it doesn't exist

```
func handleStatsValue(tag: Int ) {
    if var innerDict = dictionary["Score"] {
        if let value = innerDict[tag] {
            innerDict[tag] = value + 1
        } else {
            innerDict[tag] = 1
        }
        dictionary["Score"] = innerDict
    }    
}
```

Although the code looks a bit strange with the hardcoded key "Score", maybe it would be better to have multiple simple dictionaries instead, like

```
var score: [Int, Int]()
```

or if you prefer

```
var score = Dictionary<Int, Int>()
```